# Search for google contact based on Email

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to find a contact by his email using [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest).

We are using the [Create Contact method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact).
I'm run this method with all the [relevant scopes](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) and using [oAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) with refresh token.

```
 HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setTransport(transport)
            .setClientSecrets(googlePeopleKey.getClientId(), googlePeopleKey.getClientSecret())
            .build().setRefreshToken(googlePeopleKey.getRefreshToken());

    this.peopleService = new PeopleService.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, googleCredential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
```

When we use the [Create Contact method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact) - Google search for the given email in the system (google plus and more tools) and enrich the contact with an existing data about the user such as photos, gender, profiles and a lot more.

```
public Person createContact(String email) {
    Person requiredPerson = new Person();
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.set("value", email);
    requiredPerson.setEmailAddresses(Arrays.asList(emailAddress));

    try {
        PeopleService.People.CreateContact createContact = peopleService.people().createContact(requiredPerson);
        return createContact.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Could not perform Google people search for email {}", email, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But, I struggled to get all the information about the users. 
We have limitations of 90 calls per second but our system not near this limit.

With two different users, it seems like after 40-50 calls the API start to return empty contact (without photos, gender and more..)

Although the next day it found all the data about a specific person that the day before it returns me fewer data.

I know we have limitations of 25,000 contacts per day but we are not near this limit too.

I can really use your help to find why after 40/50 new contact, google people API start to create the contact without retrieving all the possible data in google systems.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean you are "trying to find a contact by his email"? If you are trying to implement some sort of search system by creating a contact with an email when searching for an email, that sounds like you are using the API not as it is designed and abusing it.